# From ASP.NET can I access all Sessions?

Tags: asp.net, session

I want to enumerate all the Sessions. Are they available, or do I have to keep references to them manually from Session_Start in Global.asax?

Comment: what do you want to do by enumerating through the sessions?

Comment: What I want to accomplish is fodder for another question. Consider it academic in nature if you must.

Comment: It may be possible.  I know that if you set up your session management to be stored in the database, you can enumerate through the rows.  Not sure on how you would load that serialized data into a session object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create your own session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178587%28VS.80%29.aspx) provider which gives you access to all the sessions via some special command. The built-in session handlers don't, however.

I wonder why you want to do this, though? It seems like an unusual requirement, and a possible security issue as well.

Comment: Makes we wonder if I could create a custom session provider that proxies calls through to the built-in session handlers, but provides me an "in the middle" handle to all sessions. I thought about security too but really as long as I'm not manipulating the other sessions then there's likely no cause for concern - I'm just looking at them.